# How do I remove a file from SVN's ignore list, using the command-line?

Tags: svn, command-line

I'm running Linux, and I put some files into SVN's ignore list. Now I want to remove them. But, I need to use the command-line for this purpose, not some SVN client's built-in features. How can I do that?

Answer (score 14):

Using [`propedit`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re20.html) start the default text editor to edit a property, in this case it's the one named [`svn:ignore`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) :

```
svn propedit svn:ignore .
```

Answer (score 12):

Use  the svn [propdel](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re19.html) command

Directory:

```
svn propdel svn:ignore .
```

Recursive:

```
svn propdel svn:ignore -R
```

Comment: this will remove all ignores in the directory, if you just want one use the propedit by @virtualblackfox

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove one file out of several others from svn ignore, do as @virtualblackfox says to get to your svn:delete property in a text editor.  If you see the actual file listed, e.g. (file2.txt):

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

Then simply remove it, e.g.:

```
file1.txt
file3.txt
```

But if you have a filter like *.txt, then you will need to create a black list.

Then 'svn stat' and you should see something like

```
?    file2.txt
```

Then you can 'svn add file2.txt' back in to the repository.

Answer (score 1):

To remove ignored files from file system, run:

```
svn st --no-ignore | grep "I   " | sed "s/I   //" | xargs rm
```